# Unity Detect closed white surface on ui canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, object-detection, unity-ui

I like to detect the white surface on a UI-Canvas which is enclosed by a line and fill it with a certain color or do something else with that surface. Comparable to the paint bucket tool in photoshop. The lines are generated from a .svg file, which is imported into unity. The Canvas can have multiple elements.
Do you know how to do that?
[image]

Comment: do you have code or picture to show?

Comment: I updated the question with the picture. The user should click on the white area (surrounded by the red line), the system should then recognise the area

Comment: I recommend to seperate the grahics and import the multiple image in unity in the same position. to change the color grab the image and modify its color value. to detect click from ui element use graphic raycaster more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561762/unity-how-do-i-make-an-array-of-ui-game-objects-beneath-the-cursor

Comment: awesome :) That was what I have searched for :)

Answer (score 0):

As Art Zolina III said in the comment, it´s best to seperate the grahics and import the multiple-image in unity in the same position. to change the color grab the image and modify its color value. to detect click from ui element use graphic raycaster more information here stackoverflow.com/questions/66561762/…